# ios app back button does not save cookie

Tags: javascript, ios5, ios-simulator, ios4

The feature allows us to switch back and forth between translations of languages when a specific cookie is set on our ios application.  Currently the code being used works in all browsers and you are able to navigate through the application and switch cookies using two buttons in the footer.

Once we tested feature on ios simulator the following issue occurred. When we are on a page and for example we have english selected, if we go to the next page and select Japanese the page will reload with Japanese translation, then when we press the back button to go to the previous page it reverts back to English and the cookie is no longer set.

**Back Button:**

```
<div onclick="javascript:createCookie('previousPagePath',location.pathname,(1/24/60)); history.go(-1);">
    <img src="<!--{$rewriteBase}-->images/common/previous.png" alt="" />
    <div>
        <span class="langTranslate">Back//戻る</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript used to create the cookie, by default it starts out on english ('0'). Japanese would be ('1').

**Javascript:**

```
// language selection

$(function() {
    if(readCookie('langSelect') == null) {
    // create cookie and set it to english by default
    createCookie('langSelect', '0', 1);
}
// set selected language
$('.langBtn').click(function() {
    var selectedLangCode = $(this).attr('data-lang-code');
    createCookie('langSelect', selectedLangCode, 1);
    location.reload();
});
});
```

The following Javascript is included in every footer
You will see that the first few lines are used to separate the english from Japanese as it appears in our DB like so: (English translation//Japanese translation)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// set current language
$('.langTranslate').each(function() {
    var label = $(this).text(),
    currentLang = parseInt(readCookie('langSelect'), 10),
    delimiter = '//';
    if(label.length >= 4 && label.indexOf(delimiter) != -1) {
        label = label.split(delimiter);
            if(typeof label[currentLang] !== 'undefined') {
                $(this).text(label[currentLang]);
            }
        }
});
</script>
```

The cookie is saved under any circumstances in browser however is removed when we press back button on ios, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved once we updated the Ipad unit to IOS 6